# Dynamically Saving the output from SSIS Package

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssis

Using SSIS Package, i am generating ExcelSheet as Output. I am invoking SSIS Package through C# Source Code.At present I am actually saving the file as :  pkgTR.Variables["dPath"].Value = @"c:\" + sFileName;

We want the feature Save As to the End User - Who decide to Save the file either on C:\ or D:\ or where ever he want to Save the file.

```
try
{
    string pkgTRPath = @"C:\Reports\SSISPackages\GenerateTransactionReport.dtsx";
    Package pkgTR;
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app;
    DTSExecResult pkgResults;

    app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
    pkgTR = app.LoadPackage(pkgTRPath, null);

    pkgTR.Variables["sConn"].Value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSISConn"];
    pkgTR.Variables["sDate"].Value = txtFromDate.Text;
    pkgTR.Variables["eDate"].Value = txtToDate.Text;
    pkgTR.Variables["sSortCode"].Value = drpSortCode.SelectedValue.TrimEnd();
    string sFileName = "TransactionReport_" + drpSortCode.SelectedValue.TrimEnd() + ".xls";
    pkgTR.Variables["dPath"].Value = @"c:\" + sFileName;

    pkgResults = pkgTR.Execute();
    var reportID = drpSortCode.SelectedValue.TrimEnd();

    if (pkgTR.ExecutionResult.ToString() == "Success")
    {
        Response.Write(String.Format(@"<script language=javascript>alert('Excel Report for {0} is Generated');</script>", reportID));
    }
    else if (pkgTR.ExecutionResult.ToString() == "Failure")
    {
        Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Failure:Unable to generate report!!');</script>");
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are invoking the package from C# can't you pop up a dialog in the C# before you start the package and then pass the directory path into your SSIS package when you execute it?